# JSON Formatting - Capital Letter

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

Is it possible to format the contents of a column to show the first letter of every word entered as a capital or even format all the word to capital letters?

Is this possible via the JSON formatting option?

Answer (score 1):

There is no straight forward function available in JSON formatting to capitalize the first letter of every word entered.

**Capitalize first letter**:

But, you can use CSS `text-transform` in JSON formatting which returns all the words converted to capitalized first letter.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "[$Title]",
  "style": {
    "text-transform": "capitalize"
  }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

---

**Capitalize whole word**:

You can use `toUpperCase()` function in JSON formatting which returns all the words converted to upper case.

**Syntax**:

`"txtContent":"=toUpperCase('DogFood')"` >> results in "DOGFOOD".

**Example**:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=toUpperCase([$Title])"
}
```

**Output**:

[image: **Output]

**Note**:

1. This only works on strings.
2. Only available in SharePoint Online

**Documentation**: [SharePoint JSON formatting Operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#operators)

Comment: **Additional**: You can capitalize first letter of each word using calculated formula, check [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/proper-function-61db8dc3-a6ca-456e-ab1b-e93ad47da569) OR using Power automate, check [this](https://www.tachytelic.net/2020/12/power-automate-proper-case/) & [this](https://benitezhere.blogspot.com/2020/10/how-to-do-proper-case-in-flow.html).

Comment: Hi @mtagliaferri, did you try this solution? Is it working for you?

Answer (score -1):

The previous answer does not meet your needs.   You are asking to capitalize the first letter of every word, not capitalize every letter in every word as your primary objective:

See this highly rated answer from a couple years ago:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/how-do-i-make-the-first-letter-of-a-string-uppercase-in-javascript

You will find an answer on that page.

Please mark as answer if this answers your question.

Comment: OP is asking the solution using JSON formatting in SharePoint & not JavaScript (not feasible to inject script in modern experience). Also, OP mentioned **or even format all the word to capital letters**.

Comment: Sir, he asked two questions in two separate, distinct sentences.  just because you combined them to form a singular, convenient question does not mean you are correct in your reading.

Comment: Let OP decide what he/she wants. I am not saying I am correct or you are wrong.